# Stream updates from AWS glue catalog to WebSocket React

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, websocket

I'd like to know if there's some way to stream data updates from an AWS Glue catalog to a React app by using a WebSocket or API Gateway.

thanks,
David

Answer (score 1):

take a look at this article [Poll to Push AWS](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/from-poll-to-push-transform-apis-using-amazon-api-gateway-rest-apis-and-websockets/)

You can always, hook into aws events with event Bridge.